# create array from mysql result?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to create an array(); from the mysql results/query.

**The Array OUTPUT should look exactly like this:**

```
{"1":{"info":"Rooz","lat":51.503363,"lng":-0.127625},
"2":{"info":"Michelle","lat":51.503343,"lng":-0.127567}}
```

So I tried to do it this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, lat, lng FROM positions ORDER BY id";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
$testLocs = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$testLocs[] = $row;

}
print_r(json_encode($testLocs));
```

but the OUTPUT of the code above is like this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Rooz","lat":"51.5033630","lng":"-0.1276250"},{"id":"2","name":"Michelle","lat":"51.503343","lng":"-0.127567"}]
```

I have no idea how to achieve the output that I want in an array.

Could someone please advise on this?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$testLocs[] = $row;
```

to

```
$testLocs[$row["id"]] = array("info"=>$row["name"], "lat"=>$row["lat"], "lng"=>$row["lng"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @Sean's answer: You could also use `(array) $row` instead of create the array manually with every key:

`$testLocs[$row["id"]] = (array) $row;`

If you change your query in the future, you don't have to change this line.

Answer (score 0):

PHP arrays are not built in a distinct way from JSON objects:

```
$testLocs[$row["id"]] = $row;
```

If you purposely want to exclude the `$id` property from `$row` you can remove it from the `$row` array first.

```
$id = $row["id"];
unset($row["id"]);
$testLocs[$id] = $row;
```